# PotPlayer fails to play videos after Win 10 1803 update, how to fix it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, debug, windows-10-v1803, daum-pot-player

Since the update [1803](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1803), [PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/) can play the audio of a movie but fails to play the video. And the player window seems to be duplicated and stuck there. And this is not an exception, my music player [Netease Music](https://music.163.com/) also fails to display its interface but you can click on the invisible objects on the invisible interface.

[image]

Having read some solutions, I found disabling my Intel HD Graphics adapter fixed the problem. But the screen scrolling display is not as smooth as before and the hue is getting cooler. This is thus not a good solution but implies the issue might have something to do with the display adapter. So how can I fix this in a proper way?

[image]

Comment: Similar to my problem: https://superuser.com/q/1324667/726810

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it by changing the video renderer
 Right-click ->Video -> Video_renderer -> VMR 9 renderless

Answer (score 0):

FIxed it by unchecking the read only option in the video i want to watch properties . all the best